# Reading badly encoded JSON file in PHP or node.js

Tags: php, json, node.js, unicode, utf-8

I am trying to parse http://www.spetnik.com/files/alerts.json - Chrome seems to do a fine job of it and if I download it using wget I can view it fine in VIM. However when trying to parse it with either node.js or PHP the parsing fails. I have tried all sorts of things, including mb_convert_encoding, and nothing is working. What is the easiest way to parse this JSON?

Comment: can you post the actual json, recently i had one with enclosing '"{"badjson":"hello"}"' quotes, which i just used trim($json, '"'); on

Comment: How about in node? I'm struggling to parse this endpoint with node still....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php). I had no luck with `mb_detect_encoding()` and `mb_convert_encoding()`, but `iconv` succesfully converted character encoding to UTF-8 ( `json_decode` only works with `UTF-8` encoded strings ).

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://www.spetnik.com/files/alerts.json');
$json = iconv( 'UCS-2', "UTF-8", $json );

print_r( json_decode( $json ) );
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php#97902) i found the way how to detect encoding:

```
foreach( mb_list_encodings() as $chr ){
    print_r( $chr );
    print_r( mb_convert_encoding( $json, 'UTF-8', $chr ) ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I also had to strip out the first three characters (BOM) in order to get it to parse.